# Error getting specific item/row from dataset in VB codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to run a SQL query to pull a row from a table. Then I need to get the value of a cell from a column in that table and pass it along to another SQL query. That 2nd part is where this is failing and I'm not sure why.

My code:

```
Dim var1 As Dataset1 = function1(value)
Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = var1
Me.DataGrid1.DataBind()
Dim var2 As Dataset2 = function2(var1.tables(0).rows(0).Item("Manufacturer").ToString())
```

`function1` basically just executes a few things including sql query to populate `Dataset1` with. `function2` runs a different sql query, but needs to use a value from `Dataset1` to use in the WHERE clause.

The error I'm getting is for that 2nd row, and it says `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0`.

I have also tried things like `var1.Container.Components.Item("Manufacturer").ToString()`. The result is just a different error.

I didn't include the sql query here because I know that's working. I'm binding the data from that first function to a datagrid on the page and then getting data from Dataset1 onto the page using a `DataBinder` and that works fine (and I can get the Manufacturer value using the Databinder just fine so I know that that column/cell/value all exist in the dataset). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`There is no row at position 0` means that `var1.tables(0)` does not have any rows. Does your dataset contains more then one table? If so perhaps it is something like `var1.tables(1).rows(0).Item("Manufacturer")` ? If not - that means your `function1(value)` returns dataset with an empty table.

Comment: Nope, the dataset will only contain a single table and the WHERE clause will narrow that down to a single row in that table. I don't understand how `function1(value)` can return an empty table when I'm binding var1 to a DataGrid on the page (and that displays the data just fine). If `function1(value)` was returning an empty table, then the DataGrid should be empty as well, no?

Comment: True, but just in case put a breakpoint before the second line and see what `var1.tables(0).rows.count` is equal to

Comment: So for some reason the dataset has 2 tables. No idea why. Tables(1) is evidently what I want to be using and `Rows.count` is 1 in that table. But I don't think it's pulling the `Item` value still. I'm seeing a `Item = Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As System.Data.DataRow'.` when I look at the `rows(0)` "Item" value while debugging.

Comment: Try `var1.tables(1).rows(0)("Manufacturer")` without `.Item`

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was getting the correct data both with and without `.Item`. It's just not binding to the ASP hyperlink control properly. I created a separate ASP label control to check and the text is what it should be. So I'll mark this as the answer since that problem is different from this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Glad you were able to figure it out.